# Should I sell this awesome equipment?

Tags: equipment, quality, live-sound, selling

I bet any music-lover / audiophiile knows this one.

- You own or find or get a great piece of audio equipment, be it speakers, a huge old tube amp, old mixing desk, vintage headphones, etc. for which you have no immediate use.
- Adding to the fact that you are probably already hording too much stuff [professional or personal], and are aware you should get rid of things more than collect extra things.
- A particular item is special to you because you like its' sound or quality, and those don't come around too often these days. at least not for cheap.
- Market value for old gear is usually much lower than than its' worth.

We love our gear, and getting rid of items you love can be hard, especially with rare items that YOU feel is awesome.

What is your approach in this situation?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: i guess - would you keep an S200 .. OR .. what do you do in a situation like this ?

Comment: Do you need the speakers? Yes -> Keep. Otherwise ->
Do you need the money? Yes -> Sell. Otherwise ->
Do you have room for the speakers? No -> Sell. Otherwise ->
Is it likely you will use them again? No -> Sell. Otherwise: keep em ;-)

Comment: Doh @adeer This is opinion based.

Comment: @n00dles ye i know but i need a second opinion. =]

Comment: @adeer perhaps you could edit the question to a generic form.. skip the storytelling and make it about selling equipment in general. I believe that could work.

Comment: @MichaelHansenBuur good idea, just did.

Comment: Much better - voted for reopening..

Comment: Is there anything i can / should do ?

Comment: Not really - your post needs additional reopen votes. @joshp

Comment: When im in a situation like this, for instance i had a dell laptop which was super beefed up ssd's 8gb ram , extended battery and everything but i ended up having a new one and the selling price at the moment could not even touch the price this machine actually worth, so i sold it to a friend at the market price and i myself got the pleasure of doing something nice for a friend and taking some money, otherwise it would rot in a shelf or something.. I like quality things to keep being used by people they need them and put smile on faces like they did in mine, that's why i sell them to friends!